# How long does it take the Audit Log Report to Work once configured?

Tags: auditing

I followed the steps to configure the Audit Log Report at the Site Collection Level and it still gives me

> Sorry, something went wrong. This report contains no data.

It also says that it may take some time after audit settings are changed for events to surface. How long is "some time"?

Answer (score 1):

**How long does it take the Audit Log Report to Work once configured?**

Once the audit log has been configured , then you tried to Edit item , check-in or check-out item, delete item ... etc, it should be generated based on your selection at `Site Collection Audit Settings` !

**Note :** Make sure that you are using a **site collection administrator account** to can view Audit Log Report.

Answer (score 1):

It should be quick, as long as you configured the audit settings and after that you performed some activity. Couple of things to check

- make sure you configure the audit settings when enable it on site collection
- you have proper permission to view the report.
- you perform some activity I.e upload, download, edit a document etc. I would wait for 5 min after this to check the report.

Check this link for more info.https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2

Answer (score 1):

The articles below indicates that content viewing report isn’t supported in SharePoint Online. 
Microsoft has rolled out activity logging and reporting capabilities for Office 365 via O365 Security and Compliance center.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2859803/-report-contains-no-data-error-when-you-try-to-save-the-content-viewin

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/content-viewing-audit-logs-are-still-not-supported/8d0dabbf-3341-4b2f-8b1d-6a60cf288829?auth=1

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Search-the-audit-log-in-the-Office-365-Security-Compliance-Center-0d4d0f35-390b-4518-800e-0c7ec95e946c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US